# Can you automatically retrieve a foreign document in your mongodb model using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, ninject

I would like to setup my mongo db poco models so that they automatically retreive their foreign documents, similarly to how its handled by EF and nhibernate.

This is the solution that I have come up with so far, its a bit clunky but the best that I could manage:

Basic model:

```
    public class DocumentOwner
    {
        public virtual ObjectId OwnerID { get; set; }
    }
```

Extended model with manual retrieval of foreign documents:

```
public class DocumentOwner
{
    public MongoDatabase DB { get; set; }
    public virtual ObjectId OwnerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Individual Owner
    {
        get
        {
            return this.DB.GetCollection<Individual>().FindOne(Query<Individual>.EQ(x => x.Id, this.OwnerID));
        }
    }
```

The main problem with this solution is that I have to manually inject the mongo database instance which is quite clunky, if there was a way to use ninject to inject this instance that would be a lot tidier. Even better if somehow I could use MongoDBRef to retrieve the individual without having to perform a manual query...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want some sort of repository class that owns the MongoDatabase object instead, & have it insert the returned document into your class. Saving changes might be awkward because you'd need to get document back out. If so, then maybe having the Mongo class in the object is the right thing. Either way a repository class would help.

I'd use a binding to a Func, something like `Func<MongoDatabase, DocumentOwner>` within the service to create new instances.